# Combining edits from multiple Geodatabases into a Master Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, merge, append

Is there a way to automate combining edits from multiple, single project geodatabases into a master geodatabase based off the date the edits were made without creating duplicated of the same project data in the master (based on project name)?

Edit: So I am just trying to combine daily edits from around 20 projects with their own personal geodatabases into a master personal geodatabase which holds info from around 200 projects. I am thinking of making a master csv that I update daily with with which projects I have edited that day and trying to make a tool that just pulls that day's edits and updates the master personal geodatabase with the new info. No SDE just good ol' fashioned personal geodatabases. Using ArcMap and ArcCatalog.

Comment: Wilcome to GIS@SE It would be a lot easier to get a useful answer if you expanded your question to include the types and number of databases you are using, the server technology, software systems and versions that you implement.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without ArcSDE that must be implemented within ArcGIS Desktop will need to provide custom python-scripted change detection, conflict resolution (if desired) and geodatabase synchronization.

You can start out with a script such as this and expand it. This will detect your changes and export them as delta tables. You can try to reverse engineer this to import these custom delta tables into the master geodatabase:

Change Detector

http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Geoprocessing-Model-and-Script-Tool-Gallery/details?entryID=351BEE10-1422-2418-8815-82074A3E6B6C

Regarding change detection between the geodatabases, you could write geodatabase-specific scripts that only iterate through certain feature datasets or feature classes if you generally edit the same content within a respective geodatabase. This could save a lot of processing time.

The description of your environment is exactly what geodatabase replication is designed for. I agree with PolyGeo that you're better off looking into an ArcSDE solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have a lot of details so I am assuming that you are looking for something introductory on this topic.

I recommend reading up on [Geodatabase Versioning and Replication](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/multi-user-functionality).

Comment: If you haven't got SDE then there's not much hope! There is a way to find the changes and update but only if you're prepared to do a fair bit of python/ArcObjects programming and the databases are exact (file-copy) duplicates. If you can identify the edits based on edit date then the Detect Feature Changes tool might do the job, but no guarantees. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Detect_Feature_Changes/001700000190000000/